# Whats the difference between container.ListBlobsSegmented vs blobclient.ListBlobsWithPrefix?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In Azure Blob storage, what is the difference between those two methods on those two different objects?  When would I use `ContainerInstance.ListBlobsSegmented()` vs `CloudBlobClientInstance.ListBlobsWithPrefix()`?

Does it matter if I'm using PageBlobs vs block blobs?

Answer (score 6):

ListBlobsSegmented returns blob names in pages (up to 5000) with no filtering.  The CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs uses this method under the cover to enumerate all the blobs.  It is also exposed directly via the ListBlobsSegmented method.  The ListBlobsWithPrefix allows you to filter blobs starting with a prefix.  This is used by CloudBlobClient.ListBlobsWithPrefix method.

It does not matter if it is a page or block blob.